# Understanding Swoole Rows, Bytes Limits and Memory Allocation in Laravel Octane

Tags: laravel, swoole

I have a question regarding Laravel Octane's rows, bytes, and tables.

```
    'cache' => [
        'rows' => 1000,
        'bytes' => 10000,
    ],
```

1. Why do we have to limit the number of rows and bytes in the Laravel [Octane config file](https://github.com/laravel/octane/blob/da3586897acab584bf95a624db6b2b7340321de9/config/octane.php#L150)? Can't they be unlimited like other databases, such as MySQL?
2. How does Swoole determine the byte limit? Is it calculated by `strlen` under the hood? How can we avoid the "unable to allocate memory" exception? Is this exception related to the byte limitation? Whenever this exception occurs, I have to restart my Docker container to prevent the error from happening again.

```
    'tables' => [
        'example:1000' => [
            'name' => 'string:1000',
            'votes' => 'int',
        ],
    ],
```

3. Why do we need to define an additional Swoole table in the config file? What is the difference between using `Cache::store('octane')->put()` and the `tables` key in the config file? In the example provided in the config file (string:1000), what does :1000 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because Table is built on top of shared memory, it cannot be dynamically scaled.
2. `Unable to allocate memory` is because your data Key and Hash conflict rate is more than 20%, the reserved conflict memory block capacity is insufficient, set new data will report Unable to allocate memory error and return false, storage failure, then you need to increase the $size value and restart the service.

The total memory occupied by Table is (HashTable structure length + KEY length 64 bytes + $size value) * (1 + $conflict_proportion value as hash conflict) * (column size).

3. cache for Cache::store('octane'), if not then use OctaneArrayStore https://github.com/laravel/octane/blob/42b9030564b672a38a84dc319c210d25ee410ed6/src/OctaneServiceProvider.php#L151-L153

tables for Octane::table('example').

Hope I can help you.